# RenderControl for radiobuttonlist using class not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I built a simple class 
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.IO

Public Class buildcntrl
    Function buildcontrol() As String

```
    Dim SB As New StringBuilder()
    Dim SW As New StringWriter(SB)
    Dim o As New HtmlTextWriter(SW)
    Dim d As New RadioButtonList
    d.Items.Add("True")
    d.Items.Add("False")
    d.RenderControl(o)
    Return SB.ToString()
End Function
```

End Class
When I use the class from an asp.net page like this
  Dim t As New buildcntrl
 Response.Write(t.buildcontrol)
it works fine but when use a class to call the same class I receive an error
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
When I debugged the problem it throws an error when trying to execute d.RenderControl(o)
This works fine for all the other objects except for RadioButtonList